# d3js diagonal paths in tree layout don't look right

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I was trying to copy an [example for the d3js tree layout](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html) and style it a little more, so I would understand the details. Also, I applied a class-oriented approach, as this is required by the client for the project.

I am not quite sure where I went wrong when copying it, but when I finally got it to display something, my paths from node to node look rather strange.

[image]

So, what my question is now: why?
the code should do the same as the site's above, and when looking at the curve in the inspector, the `d` attribute of the path looks the same as in the example.

```
<path d="M428.57142857142856,180C428.57142857142856,270 285.7142857142857,270    285.7142857142857,360" class="link">
</path>
```

I create the diagonal in the constructor of my object.

```
var TreeGenerator = function(nodes,links){
  this.nodes = nodes;
  this.links = links;
  this.svg = d3.select("svg");
  this.svg.attr("width",width);
  this.svg.attr("height",height);
  this.system = d3.svg.diagonal();
}
```

And use it in a method later on.

```
TreeGenerator.prototype.generateTree = function () {
  var nodes = this.nodes;
  var links = this.links;
  //for every step of depth, there is a 180 step in y direction
  nodes.forEach(function (d) {d.y = d.depth*180;});
  //counting variable used later
  var i = 0;
  //nodes get selected
  var node = this.svg.selectAll("g.node");
  var nodewithdata = node.data(nodes, function (d) {
    // for every node the id is returned
    // if there is no id, an id is generated over ++i, and returned
    return d.id || (d.id=++i);
  });
  //new group gets generated
  var nodeEnter = nodewithdata.enter().append("g");
  nodeEnter.attr("class","node");
  nodeEnter.attr("transform", function (d) {
    console.log("translation: "+d.y +", "+d.x);
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
  //Rectangle gets inserted into the group
  var rects = nodeEnter.append("rect");
  //styling of Rects
  this.styleRects(rects);
  //Text gets inserted into the group
  var texts = nodeEnter.append("text");
  //styling of Texts
  this.styleTexts(texts);
  //links (not yet created)
  var link = this.svg.selectAll("path.link");
  var linkwithdata = link.data(links, function(d) {
    return d.target.id;
  });
  console.log(linkwithdata);
  //links (creation and display)
  var enteredLinks = linkwithdata.enter().insert("path","g");
  enteredLinks.attr("class", "link");
  enteredLinks.attr("d",this.system);
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem and make these paths display as in the example?

Comment: set `path {fill : none;}` in your CSS

Comment: what he said ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make it official then...
The default value for `fill` is black. 
Set `path {fill: none;}` in your CSS.